# Swift 2 to Swift 3.0 motionManager

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cmmotionmanager

I am converting an app from swift 2 to swift 3 and I'm trying to use the CMMotionManager, but it gives me this error when I try to call the .startAccelerometerUpdates() function... No clue what's wrong though.

This is how I initialize the manager:

`let motionManager = CMMotionManager()`

Trying to call the function:

```
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) in
        self!.outputAccelerationData(data!.acceleration)
    }
```

> Error: Cannot convert value of type '(CMAccelerometerData?, NSError?)
>   -> ()' to expected argument type 'CMAccelerometerHandler' (aka '(Optional, Optional) -> ()')

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cryptic error message boils down to this: in Swift 3 `NSError` is bridged to `Error` instead. Write your code like this and the problem should go away:

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: Error?) in
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many changes in Swift3. Especially in expressions.  Many **NS** suffix of types are removed such as `NSError` to Error, `NSData` to Data. 
Therefore, change `NSError` to `Error`. And if you want to prevent performance issue by multiple instances of `CMMotionManager`, use [SwiftyMotionManager](https://github.com/JeffGuKang/SwiftyMotionManager).